# What could be the reason for grid. getCell() not working in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm using a jqgrid (version<4.6) in asp.net project

I've Written function in javascript for grid. getCell and grid.setCell.

The grid. setCell function works fine and the changes are visible. But, the grid. getCell always written false, even after hardcoding the row and columnID.

I've also verified by using the column name instead of column ID... Still getCell is false

What could be possible reasons ?

Comment: The most likely reason (out of a virtual infinity of possible reasons) is an error or unexpected behavior in the code you have written (but not posted in your question).

Comment: If you post the demo code with data it will help to resolve the problem

Comment: I'll try to post the code. The project is on desktop @ office..